# Digitization vs digitalization of science/scholarship

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is there a semantic difference between "digitization" and "digitalization" when used in the context of the advent of digital science/scholarship?

E.g., is there a difference between saying "the *digitization* of scholarship affects scientific methods" and "the *digitalization* of scholarship affects scientific methods"?

Comment: What kind of research have you already done to find an answer?

Comment: You may be adding some confusion by making [scientific method](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/scientific_method) plural and generalizing its meaning.

Comment: I've checked translation systems and dictionaries which have used both terms interchangeably, or have ascribed either to specific registers but not consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes[1]. Digitization is the process of converting analog data to a digital medium[2][3], whereas digitalization is the a trend whereby systems are being migrated to the digital world[4][5].

Therefore, 
**"the digitization of scholarship affects scientific methods"** would imply that you are transcribing printed papers into a digital medium.
**"The digitalization of scholarship affects scientific methods"** would mean scientific methods are being effected by new academics publishing papers online.

Note: with all things English, the meaning of a particular lexeme is subject to the usage within a language community, thus language users may use words like digitalization and digitization interchangeably.

References:

*[1] Brennen, J. S., & Kreiss, D. (2016, October 23). Digitalization - Brennen - - Major Reference Works. Retrieved from https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118766804.wbiect111

[2] (n.d.). Digitize definition and meaning: Collins English Dictionary. Retrieved from https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/digitize

[3] (n.d.). What is digitization? - Definition from WhatIs.com. Retrieved from https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/digitization*

[4] (2015, June 23). Digitalization. Retrieved from https://www.gartner.com/it-glossary/digitalization/

[5] Bloomberg, J. (2018). Digitization, digitalization, and digital transformation: confuse them at your peril. Forbes (April 29, 2018).

Comment: Welcome to SE ELU. We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't just state a point of view but provide evidence as to why they are correct, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Could you do that please.

Comment: @David duly noted, references have been added.